# One to many row in datatable jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

How can I create `datatable` which displays record as the following:

```
|      | SECOND |
| ONE  | THIRD  |
|      | FORTH  |
|      | FIFTH  |
```

e.g one to many. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve it with Primefaces, AFAIK. You could use a [subtable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml) instead to do something like:

```
|               ONE                 | 
| SECOND | THIRD  || FORTH  || FIFTH  |
```

Or even use a [rowExpansion](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml) utility, which I usually use for most of my one to many cases.

If your requirement is to match exactly what you ask for, you could always go with a pure JSF implementation instead and try to style it using Primefaces CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Using [subtable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml) you can display 1 to N relation data like:

```
| ONE | SECOND |
|     | THIRD  |
|     | FORTH  |
|     | FIFTH  |
```

For that you need repeat ONE in each line, but display (rendered) it for first line only. See result using RichFaces

[image: 1toN]